# JQuery load function works in Chrome, but nothing happens in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a website which should change the content div with another content div from a page, via JQuery load function.
This works fine in Chrome only when it's on a web server like wamp. If I open it in Chrome or IE, by clicking on the file, it just refreshes the page and nothing changes.
Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          event.preventDefault();
        $("#menu-services").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
          $(".content").load('services.html .content-holder');
        });
      });
      </script>


 <div id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="menu-home" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu-services" href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a id="menu-tour" href="">Tour</a></li>
        <li><a id="menulogin" href="">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
<!-- the content div -->
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-holder">
some html text
</div>
</div>
```

I tried inserting 'return false;' but still nothing happens.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: You are trying to prevent the default action of the document being ready - that doesn't bode well for you. If I didn't know any better, I'd say you were one of the many people who jQuery has made less competent than they might otherwise be.

Comment: @Kolink Can yo be more specific please? I tried removing 'event.preventDefault()', but then it works in IE and not in Chrome. It also doesn't work on the web server.

Comment: Are you saying the problem in IE only happens if you try to run the files locally rather than from a webserver? I'd expect weird results if trying to use ajax methods like `.load()` on local files.

Comment: @nnnnnn It doesn't work in IE neither way. It works in chrome only when I run it from a web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `event` but you're missing the variable in the function...Plus the first `event.preventDefault()` shouldn't be there. What is it preventing? Also, what is the second one preventing? What's `#menu-services`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu-services").click(function (event) { // Look
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".content").load('services.html .content-holder');
    });
});
```

I suggest you take a look at http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/. I think you might be using it wrong...

Comment: Not even from wamp? You need to `load` from a server.

Comment: Yes I am using a local wamp server. Still the same.

Comment: Why are you using `preventDefault()`? What is it preventing from happening? What's the default behavior when you click on `#menu-services`?

Comment: I quess it should stop loading the page in 'href=""' and call the function instead. But somehow it still calls that page, which is empty and therefore only refreshes.

Comment: you're right, I saw the href empty in the code that's why I asked...I've no idea why it's not working then. You should try on a real server...

Comment: You think it has something to do with the browsers cahing of the sites?

Comment: I don't know but if it's not working and it should then it might be something with the local server.

Comment: I don't think so because it's working in chrome. Why would't it work in IE on the same server.

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you tried multiple versions? It might be a bug or something.

Comment: I'm using IE 9. I haven't tried other versions. It was really weird that it worked in IE when I removed both event.preventDefault, but only when I ran the file locally, not on the web server.

Comment: Yup, that is weird! Sorry I'm not able to help. I've no idea why this is happening. Try in other version of IE and see what happens.

Comment: I guess there's an issue with the browsers caching the pages. After I restarted it started working in IE too. The first event.preventDefault shouldn't be there. Thanks a lot. 
Now when I change content, a shadowbox funtion, activated by a link in the content stops working. Ideas why?